# Visual studio running a relevant form

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio, runtime, settings

I have three forms in C# Visual Studio. When I press the run button it only runs the first form I created. For test purposes I want to run the the second form I created. How should I do that? I use Visual Studio 2015. I just want to run only one form, or first I want to run the second form I created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Solution Explorer, go to `Program.cs` and in the `Main()` function change

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

to

```
Application.Run(new Form2());
```

or whatever your other forms are called.